# How does one use \node[inner node]{}?

Tags: nodes, trees, tikz-trees

I'm trying to reproduce a TikZ tree from a Till Tantau presentation 
([see pg.33 of this .pdf](http://www.math.u-bordeaux1.fr/gtem2008/TikZ/main.pdf))

My code is as follows:

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{trees}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[edge from parent fork down, edge from parent/.style={black,thick,draw}]

    \node[inner node]{}
        child { node {bacteria} }
        child {  node[inner node] {}
            child { node {plants} }
            child   { node[inner node] {}
                child { node[inner node] {}
                    child { node {fish} }
                    child { node[inner node] {}
                        child { node {mammals} }
                        child { node {birds} }
                    }
                }
                child { node[inner node] {}
                    child { node {dragonflies} }
                    child { node {beetles} }
                }
            }               
        };

    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

I get six errors of the type below for each of the six `node[inner node] {}` calls in the code above:

```
    ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/inner node' and I am goin
    g to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
    See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
    Type H <return> for immediate help.
    ...
    l.11 \node[inner node]
    {}
    This error message was generated by an \errmessage
    command, so I can't give any explicit help.
    Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
    and deduce the truth by order and method.
```

I couldn't find anyting pertinent on this type of usage in the [PGF manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf). Any help is welcome!

Comment: Which version of PGF are you using?

Comment: `inner node` is the name of a node with a matrix but it's not a style with PGF 2.10 CVS.

Comment: I get a similar error message with TeXLive2011 (updated within the last week)...

Comment: I use PGF 2.0 which is available as a debian package under Ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the presentation of Till Tantau does not really define the `inner node` style. I have the impression that he just wanted to illustrate that one can provide "some kind of options".

You can write

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[....,inner node/.style={fill,black,circle}]
```

to define it somehow. I tried to reproduce some filled dot, try out if this is what you want. If not, you may want to experiment with out tikz options.

Comment: The [source code](http://www.math.u-bordeaux1.fr/gtem2008/TikZ/TikZ.tgz) for the presentation can also be found [online](http://www.math.u-bordeaux1.fr/gtem2008/TikZ/TikZ.tgz). The complete source for the tree (including how to draw it that way sideways) can be found starting from line 940 in `main.tex`.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. What I initially wanted was a filled black circle at the end of each edge of the tree like in Till Tantau's figure. The above code puts it somewhere in the middle. I tried using `node[at end]` without much success...

Comment: @Caramdir Exactly what I needed. Now I'm learning PGF by leaps and bounds...